# Scrollable listbox - primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I currently have a scrollable list of items but the search bar gets scrolled too.
I want to fixate the searchbar and scroll over the rest of items

[image]

i want to reach this
[image]

any idea?

i tried sperating them but i want them in the same listbox if possible so that the filter works